# Trying to set window.location.href to object returned from interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface

I am getting this error `Type MyInterface' is not assignable to type 'string'`. I understand it, but can't come up with a good solution. `MyInterface` only returns one item which is a string. Here is the code running.

```
export interface MyInterface {
  pulledCoolData: string;
}

const getData = async (passedData: string): Promise<MyInterface> => {
  const coolData = await getDataFromAPI(passedData);

  return coolData;
};


getData(data.myData).then(response => {
    window.location.href = response;//the error is on this line because reponse is type MyInterface and it is expecting a string to be passed
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "MyInteface only returns one item"? MyInterface is a data type.

Comment: @Domino just updated question with it

Comment: An interface is not a function, it is a type. It does not "return" something, hence why it is hard to understand your question. Furthermore, assuming `getDataFromAPI` takes a string and returns a `Promise<MyInterface>`, the `getData` function you wrote is a pointless wrapper around it. This was likely not your intent. Finally, if `response` is of type `MyInterface`, then `response.pulledCoolData` is a string.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to get `pulledCoolData` from `MyInterface`:

```
getData(data.myData).then(response => {
    window.location.href = response.pulledCoolData;
});
```

I have no TypeScript experience, though, so this may be incorrect.

Comment: Yeah I had tried that, unfortunately it doesn't fix it

Comment: @programmerGuy What do you mean by "it doesn't fix it"? Help us help you by giving us more details. Do you sill get a TypeScript warning, or an error at runtime?